# When did they become invisible?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-philosophers-stone

In the first ***Harry Potter*** movie, does no one in a busy train station notice groups of people running and disappearing into a wall? This is when the newbies (Ron and Harry) run into the wall for the very first time to catch the **Hogwarts** train.

**When did they disappear?**

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/98818/why-dont-muggles-notice-people-disappearing-from-platform-9-3-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If muggles were to watch a wizard disappearing at a stone wall, they would for sure be astonished (at least).

But there is a guard at the train station that takes care, that muggles don't see that happening (and probably he is able to do the obliviate- spell, but this is never stated anywhere).

You can read about the guard in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone:

> It took quite a while for them all to get off the platform. A wizened old guard was up by the ticket barrier, letting them go through the gate in twos and threes so they didn’t attract attention by all bursting out of a solid wall at once and alarming the Muggles.

<sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17 (The Man with Two Faces)</sup>

Comment: But when Harry went the first time there was no sign of a guard.

Answer (score 4):

You are bringing up an interesting aspect of Muggle / Magic interaction. There are aspects to a magical person’s awareness that lets them see things that Muggles do not (or cannot). The entrance to Platform 9-3/4 is one of them. The entrance to Diagon Alley is another. The phone booth entrance to the Ministry of Magic is yet another. One second a magical person is there. The next second they “are not”, and they go unnoticed by Muggles.

In my opinion, they are *not actually gone*. They have entered into what a Muggle would call a distorted part of their surroundings that are no longer linearly three dimensional. Platform 9-3/4 is there; it’s just not perceived in the normal sense by Muggles. There are other examples of where three dimensional space – taken as given by Muggles – are distorted to the advantage of magical people. The Knight Bus is an example (where it can get narrower to avoid a collision). The headquarters of the Order of the Pheonix is another. The Weasley tent at the Quidditch World Cup is yet another.

They “disappear” when the magical person enters the no-longer-linear space. To a Muggle, who sees only linear space, they “disappear”. To the magical person, who has the ability to enter into the non-linear realm, they either seem to enter a place that looks normal, or least tolerable (“Fellas, why the long faces? [on the Knight Bus]).

I am sure there are other examples.

Comment: You are pretty much saying that the hogwarts recruits disappeared into another dimension in reality of the movie?

Comment: As Harry Potter said when he entered the Weasley tent: "I love magic". FYI, my answers are based on the movies. This is a *Movie* site after all.